# scanf: "%[^\n]" skips the 2nd input but " %[^\n]" does not. why?

Tags: c, scanf

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str1[128], str2[128], str3[128];

  printf ("\nEnter str1: ");
  scanf ("%[^\n]", str1);
  printf ("\nstr1 = %s", str1);

  printf ("\nEnter str2: ");
  scanf ("%[^\n]", str2);
  printf ("\nstr2 = %s", str2);

  printf ("\nEnter str3: ");
  scanf ("%[^\n]", str3);
  printf ("\nstr3 = %s", str3);

  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When it is executed only the first `scanf` stops for the prompt. The program does not stop for the next `scanf` s. But if the format string is changed from `"%[^\n]"` to `" %[^\n]"` (note the blank space before `%`), then it works okay. Does some existing newline character from the previous input buffer is automatically accepted ? But flushing `stdin` does not solve this.

What is the cause of this.

Comment: Not an answer but your life will be much easier if you look into `fgets` for this one. I generally recommend avoiding `scanf` in most situations, but here especially you're using a very powerful and hard to use function for a very simple task.

Comment: that is okay, there is no problem to input string at my end, but a curiosity about the behaviour or this feature.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You just need to 'consume' the `'\n'` character after you've read what you want.  Use the following format directive:

```
"%[^\n]%*c"
```

Which will read everything up to the newline into the string you pass in, then will consume a single character (the newline) without assigning it to anything (that `'*'` is 'assignment suppression').

Otherwise,the newline is left in the input stream waiting to immediately terminate the the subsequent `"%[^\n]"` format directives.

The problem with adding a space character to the format directive (`" %[^\n]"`) is that the space will match *any* white space. So, it will eat the newline from the end of the previous input, but it will also eat any other whitespace (including multiple newlines).

Update to your example:

```
  char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";

  printf ("\nEnter str1: ");
  scanf (fmt, str1);
  printf ("\nstr1 = %s", str1);

  printf ("\nEnter str2: ");
  scanf (fmt, str2);
  printf ("\nstr2 = %s", str2);

  printf ("\nEnter str3: ");
  scanf (fmt, str3);
  printf ("\nstr2 = %s", str3);

  printf ("\n");
```

Comment: the assignment suppression is a good solution, actually it is the first time i saw it in some good use.

Comment: ... <headdesk> I just spent the past month using "%*1[\n]" for this; +1 and thank you.

Comment: Is this a de-facto better approach than calling `getchar` to consume the trailing newline? Does this format specification require a specific standard (ie: C99)? Thanks!

Comment: @Dogbert: to be honest, I'm not a big fan of using `scanf()` to parse input. In most cases I'd probably prefer to read a line of input completely into a buffer, then parse that buffer using `sscanf()`, `strtok()` or something even better.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I figured the same. I just haven't had much, if any, exposure to this `printf` format specifier, save for the `*` and it's always good to see if there's a better habit I should get into. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with this version is that it won't match, nor consume if the input is a simple "/n" (the user presses enter without a single charachter)

Answer (score 7):

When you use `scanf()` to read the strings, your format string (`%[^\n]`) tells the function to read every character that is not `'\n'`.  That leaves the `'\n'` character in the input buffer.  So when you try to read `str2` and `str3`, `scanf()` finds the first thing in the buffer is `'\n'` each time and, because of the format string, doesn't remove it from the input buffer.  What you need is a `getchar()` between the times that you read from the input buffer (often placed immediately after `scanf()`).  Since there is already a `'\n'` in the buffer, your program won't appear to hang because it won't have to wait for input for `getchar()` to receive.  Try it.  :)

For those who haven't a clue what that `scanf()` modifier does, here is a relevant excerpt from http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf -

> [
>
> Matches a nonempty sequence of
>   characters from the specified set of
>   accepted characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to char, and there
>   must be enough room for all the
>   characters in the string, plus a
>   terminating null byte. The usual skip
>   of leading white space is suppressed.
>   The string is to be made up of
>   characters in (or not in) a particular
>   set; the set is defined by the
>   characters between the open bracket [
>   character and a close bracket ]
>   character. The set excludes those
>   characters if the first character
>   after the open bracket is a circumflex
>   (^). To include a close bracket in the
>   set, make it the first character after
>   the open bracket or the circumflex;
>   any other position will end the set.
>   The hyphen character - is also
>   special; when placed between two other
>   characters, it adds all intervening
>   characters to the set. To include a
>   hyphen, make it the last character
>   before the final close bracket. For
>   instance, [^]0-9-] means the set
>   "everything except close bracket, zero
>   through nine, and hyphen". The string
>   ends with the appearance of a
>   character not in the (or, with a
>   circumflex, in) set or when the field
>   width runs out.

Comment: same question to you also: then what the trailing blank space signifies in " %[^\n]" . This will work correctly.

Comment: When you add a leading space to the format string, it is evaluated as any character that the function `isspace()` would return a truthy value for, including `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'`, etc. This means that the space character before the next non-space character in the format string is ignored.

Comment: If you use a trailing space (a space at the end of the format string), your program appears to hang. Instead of entering a blank line or using space characters, you must enter what the value of str2 will be. The same for str3 and when it asks for str3's value, you would enter a value that won't appear. For example, use `"%[^\n] "` instead of `"%[^\n]"`/`" %[^\n]"`. Your newline will be ignored as specified...and eaten by the trailing space in the format string. Since scanf didn't get a '\n' character, it will want more data. str2 will have that value and str3 will have str2's value.

Comment: Note that the C99 standard doesn't actually specify the behavior of `"%["`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Very true.  However, it would seem that it is part of the POSIX.1 specification as both [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d(v=vs.71).aspx) and [SuSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fscanf.html) specify it.

Comment: @Chris - what do you mean C99 doesn't specify `"%["`?  It's in 17.9.6.2 "The fscanf function".

Comment: i will have a look at what the standards have to say about the scanset.

Comment: @Michael Burr - IIRC my copy (a pre-final draft) left the behavior of `"%["` implementation defined.

Comment: @Chris: there are parts that are implementation defined, such as using `'-'` to specify a range.

Answer (score 3):

ALSO:
To read a string:

```
scanf("%[^\n]\n", a);
```

// it means read until you meet '\n', then trash that '\n'

:)

Comment: The final `'\n'` does not only consume a `'\n'` but any number of whitespace `char` like `'\t'` and `' '` as well as the `'\n'`.  It will continue consuming (trashing) whitespace until a non-whitespace is found, which is put back into `stdin` for the next IO operation.

Comment: what do you mean by trashing? You mean it is eliminated?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a getchar() after the scanf() function.

Comment: The main point of the question at that time was to understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a bit further to above answer-
If we want to remove some specific pattern, suppose numbers 0-9, from input stream then we will have to use getchar() for flushing buffer.

```
scanf("%[^0-9\n]", str1);
while(getchar() != '\n'); // this approach is much better bcz it will
                         // remove any number of left characters in buffer.
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

So here if you pass ashish019 then only ashish will be copied to str and 019 would be left in buffer so for clearing that you need getchar() multiple times.

Answer (score -3):

use `fflush(stdin)` to clear the input buffer after reading each input.

Comment: `fflush()` is designed to be used only with the output streams. It might seem to work, but the standard defines undefined behavior if used with stdin. **So do not use it with stdin.**