# How the scanf function works?

Tags: c

I have coded the following codes,but there was a problem

```
char p[20];
int n;
errno = 0;
n = scanf("%[^\n]",p);
if (1 == n)
{
    printf("%s\n",p);
    scanf("%[^\n]",p);  /*no waiting for input*/
    printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = scanf("%[^\n]",p);
```

This says scan every character except `\n` ie <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. So it allows you to enter a string and you would have pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This <kbd>ENTER</kbd> character is still in `stdin` buffer which will terminate your next `scanf` statement

```
scanf("%[^\n]",p);/*no executed*/
```

and hence it *seems to you* that it dint execute! `scanf`, reads first from the buffer, if it doesn't find sufficient data there, then waits for your input.

Feed the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you entered first to some function like `getchar()`. ie add a `getchar()` before your second `scanf` and now your second `scanf` will accept input from `stdin`

Something like

```
if (1 == n)
{
    printf("%s %d\n",p,n);
    getchar();
    scanf("%[^\n]",p);/*no executed*/
    printf("%s\n",p);
}
```