# Is there a c-runtime function equivalent of fscanf, which contains the same parameter list?

Tags: linux, scanf, libc, archlinux

Hi i have a function like this

```
while(fscanf(fp,"\n%d\t%s\t%s\t%X%X\t%d\t  \n",&record.Index,record.Name,record.Empcode,&record.CSN_MSB,&record.AccessRights)!=EOF)
 {
  printf("\nIndex: %d\nEmployee Name: %s\nEmpcode: %s\nCSN: %X\nAccessRights: %d\n",record.Index,record.Name,record.Empcode,record.CSN_MSB,record.AccessRights);
  sprintf(CSN_MSB_LSB,"%X", record.CSN_MSB);
  if(strncmp(CSN_MSB_LSB,str,8)==0)
  found=1;       
 }
```

in this code my fscanf is reading only one line from file pointer fd, i want to read all the lines from the file.
how i can i do this 
with same fscanf function or else any alternative which contains the same parameter list for the fscanf function please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I would try something of the sort:

```
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d%s%s%X%X%[^\n]*c",
          &record.Index,record.Name,record.Empcode,
          &record.CSN_MSB,&record.AccessRights)!=EOF)
    {
```

Though, it is worth noting that you are scanning 6 items and only storing 5. Also, you are using sscanf which takes a pointer to a character and passing it a file pointer (file descriptor), you want to use fscanf if reading from a file. The last number you scan never gets stored. The "[^\n]" says scan until a newline and takes place of the last number you are scanning for (though you don't save it in your example) and the "*c" consumes that newline. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why).