# Issues ignoring spaces with scanf when using multiple scanf's in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to use `scanf` multiple times in a small program to grab inputs that are guaranteed to have spaces. From the multiple threads I've browsed though it seems like `scanf("%[^\n]", string);` is the way to get it to ignore spaces. This works, for one line, but any other scanf's after that line don't go through and their respective strings put out the following:

```
Action: J���J
 Resolution: J:F�J�B�J
```

Here is a bit of example code that I thought would work, but does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];

    printf("Situation?\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str1);

    printf("Action Taken?\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str2);

    printf("Situation: %s\n",str1);
    printf("Action: %s\n",str2);
}
```

If I input "Just a test" when prompted for the situation the following happens:

```
Situation?
just a test
Action Taken?
Situation: just a test
Action: ��_��?�J.N=��J�J�d�����J0d���8d��TJ�J
```

Any suggestions or solutions (excluding `fgets`)? An explanation of what's happening would be great as well.

Edit: The solution over at [scanf: "%[^\n]" skips the 2nd input but " %[^\n]" does not. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045)

Adding in the `char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";` worked 100%.

```
char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";

  printf ("\nEnter str1: ");
  scanf (fmt, str1);
  printf ("\nstr1 = %s", str1);

  printf ("\nEnter str2: ");
  scanf (fmt, str2);
  printf ("\nstr2 = %s", str2);

  printf ("\nEnter str3: ");
  scanf (fmt, str3);
  printf ("\nstr2 = %s", str3);

  printf ("\n");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why?

Comment: The `[` specifier must find at least 1 character else the match fails. You will find that `scanf` returns `0` in this case (you should always check the return value of scanf) and then you cause undefined behaviour by using uninitialized variable `str2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
```

to

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str1);//consume a newline at the end of the line
```

Answer (score 2):

Number of approaches:

Rather than the following which does not consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` (which is *the* problem):

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str1);
```

1. Consume the trailing newline.  `"%*1[\n]"` will only consume 1 `'\n'`, but not save it.

   ```
   scanf("%99[^\n]%*1[\n]" ,str1);
   ```
2. Consume the trailing newline on the next `scanf()`.  The `" "` consume previous and leading white-space.

   ```
   scanf(" %99[^\n]", str1);
   ```
3. Use `fgets()`, but of course, this is not `scanf()`.  The best method.

   ```
   fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);
   ```

Whatever solution, limit the maximum charcters read and check the function's return value.

```
    if (fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
```

Comment: One question: why add `99`?

Comment: @Tony 99 limits the numbers of characters (width) scanned and stored in `str1`.  After storing up to 99 `char`, the `\0' is appended.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `99` would be some special number here and It seems fine for me to use other number.

Comment: @Tony  As with other `scanf()` specifier, `"%5d"` says to scan up to 5 characters, so values -9999 to 99999 could be scanned and saved.  The 99 is a width parameter here for `str1[100]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an immediate answer for you problem, why don't you simply use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) (or even [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)) if you want a line of input ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one:** Using `scanf`

If you still want to read it by `scanf`, the answer provided by @chux and @BLUEPLXY is good enough. Like:

```
 scanf(" %[^\n]", str);  //notice a space is in the formatted string
```

or

```
 scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
```

**Solution two:** Using `getline()`(although it is a POSIX extension)

[Because using `gets()` and 'fgets()` are unreliable sometimes.](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html)