# Unable to find error in C code

Tags: c

When I execute the following code program exits before I get to input any string for word 2. i.e scanf-word2 is not executed. Why? I am using mac and I can't make the 2nd scanf execute in both codelite and terminal(using make)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word1[20], word2[20];

    printf("enter word 1 : ");

    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word1);

    printf("enter word 2 : ");

    scanf("%[^\n]s",&word2);

}
```

Comment: worked beautifully. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf: "%\[^\n\]" skips the 2nd input but " %\[^\n\]" does not. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why), [Simple C scanf does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work), [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562218/c-multiple-scanfs-when-i-enter-in-a-value-for-one-scanf-it-skips-the-second-s)... etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending **wrong argument type** into `scanf()` for scanning strings and **not checking for whitespaces**... Instead use `scanf` this way :

```
scanf("%19[^\n]",word1); 
//and also
scanf(" %19[^\n]",word2); 
// a space in front to consume white spaces and don't put & before string variable
```

- While scanning a string using `scanf()` the argument to be sent must be of the type `char*` but not `char`
- here, `word1` and `word2` are of the type `char*` whereas `word1[i]` and `word2[i]` are of the type `char`
- `%19[^\n]` would  allow scanning only `19` characters including whitespaces (i.e, `'\0'`, `'\n'` `' '`) and will leave the last index for terminating null character `'\0'`. Here, 19 iss known as [**width field**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx) *(click to know more)*

---

Further reading :

[***Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?***](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: 19 is a random value you chose?

Comment: Nope... Since 20 is the max size of string... %19[^\n] allow scanning only 19 characters including whitespaces and will leave the last block for terminating null character

Answer (score 2):

If you read the manual page [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Then this bit does not make sense

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",&word1);
```

It should be

```
if (scanf("%19[^\n]",word1) == 1) ....
```

And ditto for `word2`

**EDIT**

For word 2

```
if (scanf("\n%19[^\n]",word2) == 1) ....
```

Comment: OP would need to take care of newline character in `stdin` , adding check won't do that .

Comment: The check ensures that `word` is filled in

Comment: Yes, specifically I mentioned about the second `scanf` . Ahh you have updated the answer  :).

Answer (score 0):

Prevent buffer overflow by passing the maximum number of characters to `scanf` and skip the `'\n'` with a dummy format:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char word1[20], word2[20];

    printf("Enter word 1: ");
    fflush(stdout);  // make sure prompt is output
    if (scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", word1) < 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter word 2: ");
    fflush(stdout);  // make sure prompt is output
    if (scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", word2) < 1)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `scanf` to read lines has some side effects: you cannot read an empty line this way and you have to hard code the buffer size in the format string in an awkward way.

I would instead suggest using `fgets()` and stripping the trailing `'\n'` this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char word1[20], word2[20];

    printf("enter word 1 : ");
    fflush(stdout);  // make sure prompt is output
    if (fgets(word1, sizeof word1, stdin) == NULL)
        return 1;

    word1[strcspn(word1, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the \n if any

    printf("enter word 2 : ");
    fflush(stdout);  // make sure prompt is output
    if (fgets(word2, sizeof word2, stdin) == NULL)
        return 1;

    word2[strcspn(word2, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the \n if any

    printf("word1: |%s|, word2: |%s|\n", word1, word2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps checking the return values `scanf` you be a good idea

Comment: @EdHeal: indeed it would be a good idea, I'll update the answer, but it would be good to use `word1` and `word2` too;-)

Comment: Perhaps adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` may be required

Comment: @EdHeal: Flushing `stdout` is usually not required if both `stdin` and `stdout` are bound to the terminal, but I guess it may be useful on some systems.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `getchar()` before second `scanf();`
There is already a `'\n'` char in the buffer. In the second `scanf()` operation it reads that character and terminates the program.