# scanf function is skipping input in for loop in C Programming

Tags: c, scanf

I have write simple code using structure method and in that code I am taking string(name) as input using for loop for 3 students. For 1st iteration each line in for loop is working as it should be.... but problem comes on second iteration... in second iteration `scanf` is skipping input for string (name)...

My code is as below :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student_data
{
    char name[5];
    int dsd;
    int dic;
    int total;  
};

void main()
{
    struct student_data s[3];


    int i;

    for(i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Name of Student\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]",s[i].name);         // Problem occures here in     
                                       //  second iteration  

        printf("\nEnter marks of DSD\n");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].dsd);

        printf("Enter marks of DIC\n");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].dic);


        s[i].total = s[i].dsd+s[i].dic;     

    }

    printf("%-10s %7s %7s  %7s\n ","Name","DSD","DIC","Total");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {

       printf("%-10s %5d  %6d      %6d\n",s[i].name,s[i].dsd,s[i].dic,s[i].total);
}
```

}

Comment: You are using `scanf()` wrong anyway. You MUST check for the return value if you don't wan't to read uninitialized memory. And you don't want to, because it's undefined behavior. The problem with `scanf()` is that it's really hard to make it useful in a real life program, that's why it's rarely used, nevertheless it's the first thing every one learns about [tag:c]. Please read `scanf()`'s documentation, you might find out yourself why it's not working, and why it hardly does.

Comment: wrong `scanf()` . use `scanf(" %4[^\n]",s[i].name);` instead.

Comment: @AbhishekTandon if we are using `scanf(" %4[^\n]",s[i].name);` . Can we give name more than 4 characters?

Comment: By the way, your code will fail because you iterate 3 times (when i=0,1,2) over an array of 2 elements (elem=0,1). Don't you get a Seg Fault on the 3rd iteration?

Or maybe it's just a type when you wrote 
'struct student_data s[2];' 
and simply meant 
'struct student_data s[3];'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code was that you defined the `student_data s[2]` which is a array of size two, but in the loop, you are looping `for (i=0; i<3; i++)` which is valid for an array of size 3. This small modifications will work fine:

```
 int main()
{
struct student_data s[2];  // array of size 2


int i;

for(i=0; i<2; i++)      // i will have values 0 and 1 which is 2 (same as size of your array)
{
    printf("Enter Name of Student\n");
    scanf("%s", s[i].name);

    printf("\nEnter marks of DSD\n");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].dsd);

    printf("Enter marks of DIC\n");
    scanf("%d", &s[i].dic);

    s[i].total = s[i].dsd+s[i].dic;

}

    printf("%-10s %7s %7s  %7s\n ","Name","DSD","DIC","Total");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)   // same mistake was repeated here
    {
        printf("%-10s %5d  %6d     %6d\n",s[i].name,s[i].dsd,s[i].dic,s[i].total);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thnx ur solution worked.... but i still want to know why %[^\n] was skipping input from user ??

Comment: @rushank27 take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why